# how to make quiz questions appear one at a time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

JavaScript noob here. I'm trying to make a quiz app I'm working on, but I really don't know how to proceed. I've written out all the questions with html.

Here's the situation: this quiz has no correct answers, just answer values. The code is supposed to add up all the values of each question and display a final score/description at the end based on the total number of points accumulated:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quiz.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript" href="quiz.js"></script>
<title>What Type of Date Are You? (Dude Edition)</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>What Type of Date Are You? (Dude Edition)</h1>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>1. You see a girl waiting at the bus stop. She is exactly your type. How do you get her number?</p>
    <form class="options">
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question1" value=4>You walk right up to her, strike up a conversation, and ask for her number<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question1" value=3>You wait a few days until you get the courage to go and talk to her<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question1" value=2>You tell one of your mutual friends that you like her<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question1" value=1>You wait for her to come to you</br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>2. You guys decide to go out on a date. Where do you decide to take her?</p>
    <form class="options">
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question2" value=4>You take her out for a short coffee and talk about life and relationships<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question2" value=3>You take her out on a creative date and ask her questions about her life and you respond in kind, tried-and-true interview-style<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question2" value=2>You take her out to a nice restaurant and dress in your best clothes. You ask the same questions as above<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question2" value=1>You take her to the best restaurant and hope that your clothes does most of the talking. If not, you've got great stories to tell up your sleeves<br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>3. You think you had a great first date. What do you do between now and your second date?</p>
    <form class="options">
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question3" value=4>You send her a text telling her you'll have out again soon. No big deal. Another date with another girl, coming up!<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question3" value=3>You send her a text telling her how much fun you had and can't wait for the next date.<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question3" value=2>In addition to doing above, you call her and ask her how she thinks the date went and when/where the next date is<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question3" value=1>In addition to doing above, you think about how lucky you are for finally finding an amazing girl. You hope to start a relationship ASAP<br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>4. Crap! You just remembered you have a huge project due this Friday. This might be a problem. How many dates do you have this week?</p>
    <form>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question4" value=4>More than 5. You're going to have to cancel one of them.<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question4" value=3>You have a few dates in the pipeline, just testing the waters. You can still make the dates<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question4" value=2>You have one date because you're a one woman kind of guy<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question4" value=1>You have one date. You don't date much, in general.<br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>5. Finally, how spontaneous are you?</p>
    <form>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question5" value=4>YOLO is your middle name. Your amusement > all else<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question5" value=3>You may not be the most wild or crazy person, but you are definitely down for good times<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question5" value=2>You like to have fun as much as the next guy, as long as things don't get too out of hand<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question5" value=1>I like to plan ahead, no matter what the situation, work or play<br>
    </form>
</div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id='next' value="Next" onlick="sum_values()">
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
answers = new Object();
$('.option').change(function(){
    var answer = ($(this).attr('value'))
    var question = ($(this).attr('name'))
    answers[question] = answer
})
var item1 = document.getElementById('questions');

$('#next').click(function(){
    var result = sum_values()
    //do stuff with the result
    alert(result);
});

})

function sum_values(){
var the_sum = 0;
for (questions in answers){
    the_sum = the_sum + parseInt(answers[question])
}
return the_sum
}

$('#next').click(function(){
$('.questions').fadeOut();
$('.questions' + $(this).html()).delay(450).fadeIn();
```

I know it's filled with errors, but I'm looking to learn as much as possible so any critiques/help would be appreciated. I'm obviously nowhere near done, so I won't take it personally.

Comment: You might consider posting this at "Code Review" instead - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - Stack Overflow is for technical Q&A, you don't really have a technical question here... more of a "please review", which is exactly what "Code Review" is for.

Comment: @Snixtor - it was recently pointed out to me that `codereview` wants working code to review, not broken code that needs fixing. However [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) doesn't seem right either.

Comment: @StephenP - Sounds like johnyz question might be a bit between categories. On the one hand, *"looking to learn as much as possible so any critiques/help would be appreciated"* is a bit of a CodeReview question. But non-working suggests it belongs on SO. But *"filled with errors"* doesn't typically go down well on SO, the most typical response being (rightly so) *"what have you done to try and fix those errors?"*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer the question of "how to make quiz questions appear one at a time in javascript", there are a hundred ways to merengue a purple flamingo. One solution would be to get the total amount of questions and keep track of the current question being displayed. Then when a user clicks next, hide the current question and display the next.http://jsfiddle.net/3kpFV/

```
//Store the total number of questions
var totalQuestions = $('.questions').size();

//Set the current question to display to 1
var currentQuestion = 0;

//Store the selector in a variable.
//It is good practice to prefix jQuery selector variables with a $
$questions = $('.questions');

//Hide all the questions
$questions.hide();

//Show the first question
$($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();

//attach a click listener to the HTML element with the id of 'next'
$('#next').click(function () {

     //fade out the current question,
     //putting a function inside of fadeOut calls that function 
     //immediately after fadeOut is completed, 
     //this is for a smoother transition animation
     $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeOut(function () {

        //increment the current question by one
        currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;

        //if there are no more questions do stuff
        if (currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {

            var result = sum_values()

            //do stuff with the result
            alert(result);

        } else {

            //otherwise show the next question
            $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer by Professor Allman is a very creative answer. I was looking for developing some fancy quiz using core java script...however... [Slick Quiz](https://github.com/jewlofthelotus/SlickQuiz) - This jquery plugin is something I need. It's clean and easy to customize.

[Demo Quiz](http://www.iknowmine.org/slickQuiz_example.html)

All you need is to create a PHP script  that exposes all your quiz data in JSON. This plugin supports many configurations by default.

Answer (score -1):

```
#For the Next Prev Question or Survey Question to show and hide.#
<div class="question"></div>


 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center ">
         <div class="button hide col-md-2 btn btn-primary mt-5 btn-lg" id="next">Next</div>
            <div class="button hide col-md-2 btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-5 ml-2" id="prev">Prev</div>
        </div>
    ##
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
    
    
    
    
    
     //Store the total number of questions
    var totalQuestions = $('.question').size();
    //alert(totalQuestions);
    //Set the current question to display to 1
    var currentQuestion = 0;
    //Store the selector in a variable.
    //It is good practice to prefix jQuery selector variables with a $
    $questions = $('.question');
    $prev=$('#prev');
    $next=$('#next');
    
    
    
    
    //Hide all the questions
    $questions.hide();
    
    
    
    
    $prev.hide();
    //Show the first question
    $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
    //attach a click listener to the HTML element with the id of 'next'
    $('#next').click(function () {
         //fade out the current question,
         //putting a function inside of fadeOut calls that function 
         //immediately after fadeOut is completed, 
         //this is for a smoother transition animation
         $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeOut(function () {
            //increment the current question by one
            currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
            if(currentQuestion<=1) $('.button').fadeIn();
           //alert(currentQuestion);
            if (isNaN(currentQuestion) || currentQuestion == totalQuestions ) {
         $('#next').fadeOut();
        $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
       }
            //if there are no more questions do stuff
            if (currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {
               // var result = sum_values()
                //do stuff with the result
                //alert(totalQuestions);
                $('#prev').fadeIn();
                $('#next').fadeOut();
                currentQuestion=currentQuestion-1
                $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#next').fadeIn();
                //otherwise show the next question
                $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
    
    $('#prev').click(function () {
    //fade out the current question,
    //putting a function inside of fadeOut calls that function 
    //immediately after fadeOut is completed, 
    //this is for a smoother transition animation
    $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeOut(function () {
       //Decrement the current question by one
       currentQuestion = currentQuestion - 1;
       //if there are no more questions do stuff
       if (isNaN(currentQuestion) || currentQuestion <= 0 ) {
        $('#prev').fadeOut();
        $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
       }
       if (currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {
           currentQuestion=currentQuestion-1
           $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
       } else {
        $('#next').fadeIn();
           //otherwise show the next question
           $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
       }
    });
    
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Answering with code only does not help the OP understand the solution or why this solution in the first place. I'd suggest adding context to your answer and removing some of the unused code in your example (commented out `alert` for example)