# Asking one query per page in a javascript quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a totally beginner of HTML and javascript and I need to write a multiple choice quiz made of  radio buttons with the following features:

1) it should collect all answers into an array. For instance, the i-th element of the array is 3 if the user selected the third answer in the i-th question. There is no final score, neither a right/wrong answer. At the end of the quiz I just need to show the answers.

2) it should post one question at a time (one question per page).

A similar problem was already discussed in SO at [how to make quiz questions appear one at a time in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348725/how-to-make-quiz-questions-appear-one-at-a-time-in-javascript)

and the proposed JSfiddle example seems to be a good starting solution, but I don't know how to use it. I tried to insert the javascript between `<head>` and `</head>` and the html code between `<body>` and `</body>` of an html file, but it doesn't work. Can someone kindly post an html code solving my problem?

Comment: @Jack my thoughts exactly

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quiz.js"></script>
</head>
```

**quiz.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
answers = new Object();
$('.option').change(function(){
    var answer = ($(this).attr('value'))
    var question = ($(this).attr('name'))
    answers[question] = answer
})
var item1 = document.getElementById('questions');

var totalQuestions = $('.questions').size();
var currentQuestion = 0;
$questions = $('.questions');
$questions.hide();
$($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
$('#next').click(function(){
    $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeOut(function(){
        currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
        if(currentQuestion == totalQuestions){
               var result = sum_values()
               //do stuff with the result
               alert(result);
        }else{
        $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
        }
    });

});
});


function sum_values(){
var the_sum = 0;
for (questions in answers){
    the_sum = the_sum + parseInt(answers[question])
}
return the_sum
}
```

**html**

```
<body>
<div>
    <h1>What Type of Date Are You? (Dude Edition)</h1>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>1. You see a girl waiting at the bus stop. She is exactly your type. How do you get her number?</p>
    <form class="options">
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question1" value=4>You walk right up to her, strike up a conversation, and ask for her number<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question1" value=3>You wait a few days until you get the courage to go and talk to her<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question1" value=2>You tell one of your mutual friends that you like her<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question1" value=1>You wait for her to come to you</br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>2. You guys decide to go out on a date. Where do you decide to take her?</p>
    <form class="options">
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question2" value=4>You take her out for a short coffee and talk about life and relationships<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question2" value=3>You take her out on a creative date and ask her questions about her life and you respond in kind, tried-and-true interview-style<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question2" value=2>You take her out to a nice restaurant and dress in your best clothes. You ask the same questions as above<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question2" value=1>You take her to the best restaurant and hope that your clothes does most of the talking. If not, you've got great stories to tell up your sleeves<br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>3. You think you had a great first date. What do you do between now and your second date?</p>
    <form class="options">
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question3" value=4>You send her a text telling her you'll have out again soon. No big deal. Another date with another girl, coming up!<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question3" value=3>You send her a text telling her how much fun you had and can't wait for the next date.<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question3" value=2>In addition to doing above, you call her and ask her how she thinks the date went and when/where the next date is<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question3" value=1>In addition to doing above, you think about how lucky you are for finally finding an amazing girl. You hope to start a relationship ASAP<br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>4. Crap! You just remembered you have a huge project due this Friday. This might be a problem. How many dates do you have this week?</p>
    <form>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question4" value=4>More than 5. You're going to have to cancel one of them.<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question4" value=3>You have a few dates in the pipeline, just testing the waters. You can still make the dates<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question4" value=2>You have one date because you're a one woman kind of guy<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question4" value=1>You have one date. You don't date much, in general.<br>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="questions">
    <p>5. Finally, how spontaneous are you?</p>
    <form>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question5" value=4>YOLO is your middle name. Your amusement > all else<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question5" value=3>You may not be the most wild or crazy person, but you are definitely down for good times<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question5" value=2>You like to have fun as much as the next guy, as long as things don't get too out of hand<br>
        <input class="option" type="radio" name="question5" value=1>I like to plan ahead, no matter what the situation, work or play<br>
    </form>
</div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id='next' value="Next" onlick="sum_values()">
</body>
```

**updated after OP's comment**

Put this code at the top of the page in script tag

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('div.questions').find('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.questions').each(function () {
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
            $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a button that if pressed reloads the page unchecking all radio buttons previously checked? So far, reloading the web page with `window.location.reload()` the radio buttons keep their value.

Comment: @user2696676 updated the answer kindly check  .

Comment: In the js file I added  `function resetForms() {
    for (i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
        document.forms[i].reset();
    }
    window.location.reload();
}` doing the job.